# Laravel 8 dependency injection error: Target class ... does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Could someone explain what wrong with this code and what should I do?

I have a *CustomerManager.php* file located in *app\BusinessLogic\Managers* folder:

```
<?php

namespace app\BusinessLogic\Managers;

class CustomerManager 
{
    public function putItem()
    {
        // some code
    } 
}
```

This class should be injected into *RetailController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use app\BusinessLogic\Managers;

class RetailController extends Controller
{
    protected $customerManager;

    public function __construct(CustomerManager $customerManager)
    {
        $this->customerManager = $customerManager;
    }
}
```

But as result error appers:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [app\BusinessLogic\Managers\CustomerManager] does not exist.
```

Comment: for one its `App` not `app` .. the the class `CustomerManager` you are referencing in the Controller would be `App\Http\Controllers\CustomerManager` since you never aliased it, not `App\BusinessLogic\Managers\CustomerManager`

Comment: oh my goodness, thank you!